Fast Polygonal Approximation of Terrains and Height Fields. blender-gis
Blender-GIS import georaster geotiff with regularized quads.
To have a good displacement where the slope changes it's necessary to use the "Dem Raw Data Build". But the results is very heavy for the memory when you must perform some modifier.
So I'm looking for another way to create a mesh from a geotiff.
I found "Fast Polygonal Approximation of Terrains and Height Fields", with this https://github.com/fogleman/hmm. Very good, but difficult to use, because the result loose the georeferenced data, and it has a varying displacement.
Maybe is possibile to simplify the RAW data DEM mesh after.
In this image in the left part the result of Blender-GIS, and in the right part the result of HMM utility, view from bottom

and this is the same object mesh but in orthographic view

Thank you and happy holidays wishes

what do you mean by "lose georreferenced data" and "varying displacement"?
